# Android allow call to activity only to predefined activities/packages

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

I have an applications which has different activities. One of those activities can be called from other applications.

Is there a way to set permission that this certain activity can be called only from specified applications (e.g. com.other.application and com.different.application). I would configure those allowed applications in AndroidManifest.xml or somewhere else.

Thanks

Comment: "One of those activities can be called from other applications." That is only possible if you declared it do be able to. So I don't really understand the question. By default, any activity declared in your Manifest does not respond to implicit intents, so effectively cannot be addressed by other apps.

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either declare your activity to be accessible or not by outside of the application package, but for some application accessible or for some not is not feasible.

To make private an activity to your application you need to set property of Activity in manifest: `exported=false;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I cannot vote for it because I am missing reputation :)
I have ended up with a little trick:
`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null || extras.getString("username") == null) {
 //check the password
 this.finish();
 return;
}`

Now applications can open the activity if they provide correct username and password.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own permission and only allow apps that request that permission access the functionality.

**Define Permission**

```
<permission android:name="uk.co.packagename.mypermission"/>
```

**Set permission on activity**

```
    <activity android:permission="uk.co.packagename.mypermission" android:name=".ActivityName"/>
```

**Use Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="uk.co.packagename.mypermission"/>
```